# Matlab equivelant with following input settings of Excel Solver

Tags: excel, matlab

For Excel Solver inputs, I have set

Set Object cell:  $A$1 (ie. could be 18)

To: Min

By Changing Variable $B$1

Make unconstrained variable non-negative is checked:

Solving method: Nonlinear

I am no Math expert here, but I am trying to figure which unconstrained minimization function am I supposed to use? It looks like fminunc the questions are:

1. Do I just use the Matlab min function in objfun
   (as explained at http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminunc-unconstrained-minimization.html)
2. Would

   ```
   fminunc(@objfun,x0)
   ```

work if xo is the equivalent of $B$1 as in the Excel Solver above?

I would assume there is no need for any extra options as well to get the desired result. At least I don't see any option to control negative output.

Does this sound right? 
Thanks

Comment: The documentation for `fminunc` (http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/optim/ug/fminunc.html) says that x0 is the initial guess for the minimum. `objfun` is assumed to be a function taking in one input. If you want to have restrictions on solutions, consider `fmincon`: http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html.

Comment: Thanks but the confusing part is what to set in the objfun: eg. objfun=@(n) min(n) Sorry but that would not make sense so this is why I ask

Comment: Use anonymous functions: http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html

Comment: Based on your reference, I would use objfun=@(n) min(n) either way anonymous or not. If I am wrong, how should it be set?

Comment: `onjfun=@(n) min(n)` is an anonymous function, but it's not very useful if `n` is a scalar! Are you trying to minimise the minimum value in an array of numbers?

Comment: As said, there is no array but using the equivelant functionality of Excel solver to attempt to minimize an object cell by changing another. These numbers are non scalar. Does this make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62559/discussion-between-heavy-rocker-dude-and-david).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the non-negative output, that is a constraint and as such you should not be using an unconstrained solver (i.e. `fminunc`) but rather one that can handle contraints (i.e. use [`fmincon`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html?refresh=true)):

Your constraint is a lower bound so you use this form of `fmincon`:

```
x = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)
```

You're interested in a lowerbound which is the `lb` parameter so you'd call `fmincon` like so:

```
x = fmincon(fun, x0, [], [], [], [], 0, Inf)
```

`x0` should equal the value in cell `$B$1` before you call the solver in Excel.

For the *objective function you do* **not** *use the `min` function in Matlab*, `fmincon` will inherently try and minimize your objective function, this is the same as ticking the min box in the Excel solver. What your objective function is, is the **function** in cell `$A$1` but as a function of `x` in this case instead of `$B$1`.

So let's say in cell `$A$1` you were trying to minimize the function `=$B$1^2 + 10`, then in Matlab you need to define your function like so (using anonymous functions is easiest, you could use a function .m file instead though if the function is more complicated):

```
fun = @(x)(x.^2 + 10)
```